# How to hide the admins of a secret Facebook group?

Tags: facebook-groups

I have created a secret Facebook group. I want to hide the group admins from the rest of the members in a secret Facebook group. How to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently possible to hide group admins within a secret Facebook group.